# How to play movie clip just once?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've done some research on this site and figured out most of what I want to do. I click on a block. The block moves. When done it plays another movie clip. Problem is it loops the second movie clip. I found one query that deals with this but can't figure out how to make it work with the below code. Once the if statement is true it just keeps playing the clip (as it should), but I dunno how to make it play just once. Any suggestions much appreciated.

```
block_1.stop();
block_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, block_1_Click);
function block_1_Click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    block_1.play();

}

block_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, wavePlay);
function wavePlay(e:Event):void {
    if (block_1.currentFrame==block_1.totalFrames) {
        wave_mc.play();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe's doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aenterFrame) about the `ENTER_FRAME` event says:

> [...] Dispatched when the playhead is entering a new frame. If the playhead is not moving, or if there is only one frame, this event is dispatched continuously in conjunction with the frame rate. [...]

That means that the `ENTER_FRAME` event keeps running until you remove its listener.

Your code should be:

```
block_1.stop();
block_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, block_1_Click);
function block_1_Click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    block_1.play();

}

block_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, wavePlay);
function wavePlay(e:Event):void {
    if (block_1.currentFrame==block_1.totalFrames) {            
       wave_mc.play();
       block_1.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, wavePlay );

    }

}
```

Comment: @user30191, Was this answer useful for you? If so, Would you mind accepting it as the correct one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work